# How to use response data from callout to another Callout in a seuqnce

Tags: esb, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a sequence that perform a callout (blocking), because i need to extract some data from the response to create a payload to perform a new callout to another service.

1. The Callout

   `<callout action="nextSource" initAxis2ClientOptions="false"
           serviceURL="http://192.168.0.33:9764/services/AltaLigeraService?wsdl">
       <source type="envelope" />
       <target key="myresponse" />
   </callout>`
2. So i can log the response:

   `<property expression="get-property('myresponse')" 
        name="rta" scope="default" type="STRING" />`

   `<log level="custom">
       <property expression="$ctx:rta" name="Respuesta" />
    </log>`
3. The response log is:

   `INFO - LogMediator Respuesta = 
   <ns:nextSourceResponse xmlns:ns="http://carbon.bbva.gtko.co">
     <ns:return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:ax2431="http://vo.carbon.bbva.gtko.co/xsd" 
      xsi:type="ax2431:Automatizacion">     <ax2431:filename1>28189133_AltaLigerao_Oficina_cmarguello_20160408102300_N.txt</ax2431:filename1><ax2431:filename2>28189133_AltaLigerao_Oficina_cmarguello_20160408102300_S.txt</ax2431:filename2>
   <ax2431:modulo>ALTA_LIGERA</ax2431:modulo>
   </ns:return>
   </ns:nextSourceResponse>`
4. So i need to know the values of filename1, filename2 and modulo
   I try, with xpath, to log filename1 value but i cant do.

   `<property
       expression="fn:concat('filename - ', $ctx:rta/ns:nextSourceResponse/ns:return/ax2431:filename1)"
       name="filename1" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://carbon.bbva.gtko.co" xmlns:ax2431="http://vo.carbon.bbva.gtko.co/xsd"/>
   <log level="custom">
       <property expression="get-property('filename1')" name="filename"
           xmlns:ns="http://carbon.bbva.gtko.co" />
   </log>`

and the log:

```
`INFO - LogMediator filename = filename - `
```

i also try with the same result (same log)

```
´expression="fn:concat('filename - ', $ctx:rta/ax2431:filename1)"´

`expression="fn:concat('filename - ', $ctx:rta/filename1)"`
```

Whats the correct way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i can.
The request:

```
`<body>
  <ns:nextSourceResponse xmlns:ns="http://carbon.bbva.gtko.co">
  </ns:nextSourceResponse>
</body>`
```

The key is in the target:

```
`<callout action="nextSource" initAxis2ClientOptions="false"
                serviceURL="http://192.168.0.33:9764/services/AltaLigeraService?wsdl">
    <source type="envelope" />
    <target xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:s12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
        xpath="s11:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1]" />
</callout>`
```

after that i can access value of filename

```
`<property expression="//ns:nextSourceResponse/ns:return/ax2431:filename1"
    name="filename1" scope="default" type="STRING"
    xmlns:ax2431="http://vo.carbon.bbva.gtko.co/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://carbon.bbva.gtko.co" />`
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a test:

```
<property expression="$body/*" 
     name="rta" scope="default" type="STRING" />

<log level="custom">
    <property expression="$ctx:rta" name="Respuesta" />
 </log> 


<property expression="//ns:nextSourceResponse/ns:return/ax2431:filename1" name="Respuesta2" xmlns:ns="http://carbon.bbva.gtko.co" xmlns:ax2431="http://vo.carbon.bbva.gtko.co/xsd"/>

    <property
        expression="fn:concat('test - ', get-property('Respuesta2'))"
        name="filename1" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://carbon.bbva.gtko.co" xmlns:ax2431="http://vo.carbon.bbva.gtko.co/xsd"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="get-property('filename1')" name="filename"
            xmlns:ns="http://carbon.bbva.gtko.co" />
    </log>
```

The logs:

[2016-04-29 14:19:48,005]  INFO - LogMediator Respuesta =

```
<ns:nextSourceResponse xmlns:ns="http://carbon.bbva.gtko.co"><ns:return xmlns:ax2431="http://vo.carbon.bbva.gtko.co/xsd" xmlns
:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ax2431:Automatizacion"><ax2431:filename1>28189133_AltaLigerao_Oficina_cmarguello_20160408102300_N.txt</ax2431:filename1><ax24
31:filename2>28189133_AltaLigerao_Oficina_cmarguello_20160408102300_S.txt</ax2431:filename2><ax2431:modulo>ALTA_LIGERA</ax2431:modulo></ns:return></ns:nextSourceResponse>
```

[2016-04-29 14:19:48,007]  INFO - LogMediator filename = test - 28189133_AltaLigerao_Oficina_cmarguello_20160408102300_N.txt

If you want to use the $ctx:rta way, please use it like in this property:

```
<property expression="$ctx:rta//ns:return/ax2431:filename1/text()" 
           name="Respuesta2" xmlns:ns="http://carbon.bbva.gtko.co" xmlns:ax2431="http://vo.carbon.bbva.gtko.co/xsd"/>
```

Comment: doesnt work...
i log the $body and have this

`<property expression="$body" name="rta" scope="default"
    type="STRING" />

   <log level="custom">
    <property expression="$ctx:rta" name="Respuesta" />
   </log>`

`LogMediator Respuesta = <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"/>`

Comment: my solution work as you can see in the printed logs...so if you need a solution you can use the property "Respuesta2" tu capture the value you want to use in the concat function as a workaround.

Comment: please check the last part of my response, now it work as you like

Comment: i understand your solution, but...
i have this code in a proxy 

if i put the xml in the request , and use your first aproach the  expression="//ns:nextSourceResponse/ns:return/ax2431:filename1" works fine.

But if i try to get the value of the callout target (the response) it doesnt work, it just print blank

so, i think the problem is how to get the values from the response of the callout

Comment: ok, try to print the full body with $body expression, if the payload is there and it´s the same that you print in the response log, then you try with this:  <property expression="$ctx:rta//ns:return/ax2431:filename1/text()" 
           name="Respuesta2" xmlns:ns="http://carbon.bbva.gtko.co" xmlns:ax2431="http://vo.carbon.bbva.gtko.co/xsd"/>

Comment: thanks!!!! the problem i had was in the callout target,and the request. I post a solution i reach.